# How get a value from a Visualforce page and pass it controller before calling the controller.save method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I'm having the following snippet in the VF page:

```
<apex:inputField id="reason" value="{!case.reason}" required="true"/>
```

which is displaying some case reasons for me.

By calling the following snippet I'm able to save changes which were performed on this page:

```
<apex:commandButton id ='save' action="{!save}" value="Save" />
```

I want to get a value which I choose in the reason field to be able to perform some comparison like this:

```
public PageReference save()
{
  if (this.case.reason != 'Some Value From Page') {
    callSomeMethod();
  }
  return this.controller.save();
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: this has the hallmarks of confusion between the controller property `case` and the standard controller's Case sobject.  Use [edit] and expose your controller's constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just create a field on the apex class to hold that value. Like:

```
public String someValue{get;set;}
```

Then use that on the VF page referencing it like `{!someValue}`. Then you can use that field in the `save()` method by:

```
public PageReference save()
{
  if (this.case.reason != someValue) {
    callSomeMethod();
  }
  return this.controller.save();
}
```

Give that a try and let me know if you need me to elaborate.

If the some value String will be static then you can just do:

```
public PageReference save()
{
  if (this.case.reason != 'This Value') {
    callSomeMethod();
  }
  return this.controller.save();
}
```

Where the string is just hardcoded. I don't see anything wrong with this if the string will always be a certain value.

If the dropdown value is mapped to case.reason then you can just check the selection in the logic to determine if you run `callSomeMethod()`

Comment: I created such field in the controller and tried to add it to the VF page like {!someValue} but I'm getting the "Could not resolve the entity from value binding '{!someValue}' can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable" error - this is what I got. Probably, I forget to mentioned that I'm populating the drop-down list from "{!case.reason}" and I need to execute my function if some value was choose in that drop-down.

Comment: Is the value static? If so then why not just do `if (this.case.reason != 'Some Value)`?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault in the expression, everything woks fine.